# Flask security local development server

Tags: security, flask, localhost

I have read [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/) that Flask app must never be used on production machines when debug mode is enable. And what about a local development server without a Debug Mode? Is it safty to work on it?

Comment: When debug mode is enabled and when you hit an error in the flask app, a python prompt is dispayed where you can execute arbitrary python commands, e.g. delete everything (It has a PIN mechanism, but you should not rely on it). If no malicious user has access to the server, you are save.

Comment: But when debug mode is not enabled the only person, who has an access to the server, is me, right?

Comment: I´m confused. You want to run the development server on production? Yes you kind of can. But it doesnt hold up to any other production web-server (Apache, nginx, tornado).

Comment: Yes, when debug mode is disabled, you are safe. Although you should not use the flask inbuild server because it is slow, instead use gunicorn or nginx or whatever. If you have only a low amount of users (e.g. intern tool) the flask development server with debug disabled might work.